# Unable to get Qt5 audio to work using pulseaudio on Rpi 4

Tags: audio, hdmi, alsa, pulseaudio, qt

I'm on Raspberry pi 4 and the OS is DietPi
I configured ALSA so I could play an audio file successfully **through HDMI** using `aplay [an audio file]`
Then launched the PyQt5 app but got `PulseAudioService: pa_context_connect() failed`.
So installed PulsAaudio and enabled its service.

**The Service:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Sound Service

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --exit-idle-time=-1 --disallow-exit=true
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Now, I don't get `PulseAudioService: pa_context_connect() failed` anymore, but neither `aplay` nor in-app sounds work.
I should probably mention that `aplay` seems playing, because the console's hold (run) time is equal to the length of the audio, but there's no sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make alsa's `aplay` work by using `aplay [audio file] -D sysdefault:CARD=0` which shows that the default device has changed.
available cards (sinks in PA) can be seen using `pacmd list-sinks`. For me, cards were:
0- HDMI
*1- 3.5m Jack
in which the default was the wrong one (1).
**Make sure `hdmi_drive=2` is uncommented in `/boot/config.txt` if you consider using HDMI.**
Default sink can be changed using `pacmd set-default-sink [sink index]`

Comment: Isn't that command `pactl`?  Maybe on rPi it's different.